# Elements hidden when using Angular.js and jQuery transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've got [a page that I adapted](http://geosprocket.github.io/ssudan-eco/) from a bootstrap-based [template](http://www.blacktie.co/demo/link/), and it mostly works great. However, when I tried to add a simple filtering action with angular.js, the usual conflicts with jQuery began to appear. The one that's really bugging me is this:

Why are my angular-constructed elements taking up space, but are not visible?

The error looks like this:

[image]

Unhelpfully, the console reports no errors, and the inspector shows the exact outlines of the elements where they SHOULD be, but aren't:

[image]

. . . and [a stripped down version](http://embed.plnkr.co/9SbODrR4NUe3DuqSwYoq/preview) of the angular components works just fine on its own. Is this a common angular/jquery issue? Thanks for the assistance, in any case!

Comment: are you able to locate the element that is taking up the space

Comment: Yes. You can see in the lower image above that it shows up in chrome inspector as a series of <ul> elements. But they're not visible, even with z-index manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Is this a common angular/jquery issue?
```

No!. The reason behind the invisible list is because of your css definition of the `.grid` class in your main.css asset.

The culprit shown below:

```
.grid li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 33%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

as you can see the list is shown as `opacity: 0` rendering the list invisible. remove the opacity property definition and that should fix your problem.

```
.grid li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Another note with your ng-repeat directive definition. I think it would be better if you place the ng-repeat directive in the `<li>` tag, in your case the repeated element is the `<ul>` instead. See example below:

```
<ul class="grid effect-2" id="grid">
    <li  ng-repeat="record in dataz | filter:searchText"><h2>{{record.name}} - {{record.source}}</h2><!--<a href="{{record.subgiturl}}"><img src="images/{{record.image}}"></a>--></li>
</ul>
```